# Install Grub on a 3rd Drive - Dual Booting

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, windows-8

Right now I am dual booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04, and I have both installed on 2 different hard drives, so when I want to boot Windows, I have to enter my BIOS menu and choose the Windows drive, and vice versa for Ubuntu.

**NOTE:**

> I can boot Windows from my Ubuntu installation, but it boots slowly (not using fast-boot from BIOS), and in safe mode, also I feel like loading Grub from a separate disk would help with startup speed.

The process of having to choose between Ubuntu and Windows in BIOS whenever I want to change my OS is rather annoying, so I would like to install Grub on my 3rd drive (50GB solid state disk), and be able to boot to either Windows or Ubuntu from that menu. How would I go about doing this?